# Getting Response.Redirect to execute the redirected page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, redirect

I am trying to integrate a SSO process with an existing a web application (not MVC) that uses forms authentication. 
I create a httpHandler within Web.Config.

```
<add path="SingleSignOn/Customer/*" verb="GET,POST" type="MyApplication.SSOLoginPage, MyApplication" />
```

I land within the SSOLoginPage and verify the process.

My goal now is to be able to redirect back to the standard login.aspx page to continue to process of creating the users profile.

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(userWhoLoggedIn, False)
Response.Redirect("login.aspx?" & "Param1=" & 1 & "&" & "Param2=" & awesomeVariable & "&" & "Param3=" & boringVariable & "&" & "Param4=" & meh, True)
```

It redirect back to the login page but i need to hit enter in the browser in order to process the redirection.

The browser url contains exactly what i need 
https://myWebApplication.com/login.aspx?Param1=1&tParam2=awesome&Param3=boring&Param4=meh

But I cannot figure out why it is not actually processing my request unless I hit enter in the URL.

Comment: " in order to process the redirection" - can you elaborate on what you mean by this?

Comment: See if this helps, too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820508/asp-net-response-redirect-not-working

Comment: @Nikki9696 what I mean is it only appears the url is created with the params, The browser sits with this URL until i hit enter.  its like all it is doing is populating the URL but not actually processing.  Its like i am sitting at a breakpoint.

Comment: does that page have any cache headers?

Comment: redirect sends a 302, see if this helps at all http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12212839/how-long-is-a-302-redirect-saved-in-browser